# Convert space separated file to tab separated file

Tags: awk

I was trying to use awk to convert a space delimited file into a tab delimited file. To my surprise this didn't work as expected:

```
awk -vOFS=$'\t' '{print}' column.txt
item                 gram
tomato                500
orange               1500
bread                2000
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
item    gram
tomato  500
orange  1500
bread   2000
```

What am I missing ?

**Note:** many have suggested several alternatives, here are some of them maybe someone is interested.

```
tr -s " " "\t" <column.txt

column -t <column.txt

perl -ple "s/\s+/\t/g" <column.txt

sed "s/\s\+/\t/" <column.txt

ruby -ple 'gsub(/\s+/,"\t")' <column.txt

python -c "import sys,re; [ sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r' +','\t',l)) for l in sys.stdin ]" <column.txt
```

Comment: I just use `perl -pli -e 's/\s+/\t/g' file.txt`, personally.

Comment: @Shawn, thanks I would prefer that, but I didn't have Perl in that environment. I ended up using `tr -s " " "\t" <column.txt`. This is more or less an academic question so I can understand what happens.

Comment: to add to the good reply by @Jotne, you are missing one thing: `print` is equivalent to `print $0`, which is only one field. I believe this better explains the phrase "if you just set OFS, it does not do anything". It does do something, indeed, you are just not making use of it. Btw, this could be improved using `FS` to cut columns from your file and output then `print $1,$2`, which explicitly makes use of `OFS`.

Comment: @DaemonPainter from the documentation, $0 stands for the full record not a field, and I assumed it's different than $1,$2... etc.

Comment: yes, indeed. In the end, whatever `$x` you ask to print, is a single field output. So, printing only `$0` won't make use of the output field separator. When I say that `print $1,$2` explicitly makes use of the `OFS` it is because of the comma. To recap, to have an output field separator, you need at least to output two fields. `print` or `print $0` only outputs one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

If you just set OFS, it does not do anything.  By setting `$1` to `$1` it will use the OFS since field has changed.  `1` is always true, so it will print the line.  Same as `{print}`

Comment: There is a simpler explanation to this, and it is carried out in the comments under the original question. There is no need to guess in programming, much of it breaks down to good explained rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

can be further truncated down to

```
mawk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} (NF==1) || ($1=$1)' file.
```

$1 = $1 isn't free. NF==1 will bypass it for any row that just happens to not have any spaces (just more flexible generic solution). Successful $1 = $1 returns true so the extra } 1' outside the braces is slightly superfluous.